# macos modal new window, windowController's windowDidLoad called after its contentView's viewDidLoad?

Tags: swift, macos, nsviewcontroller, nswindowcontroller

I had a macos App using storyboard and there're two windows in the storyboard for it.

If I click a button on the first window, it will modal to the second window, but I found the new window's contentView loaded first, and then it's the window load. How could this be?

code as below:

```
+-----------+      +------------+
|           |      |            |
|  Window A |      | Window B   |
|           |      |            |
+-----+-----+      +-----+------+
      v                  v
+-----+-----+      +-----+-------
| View A    |      | View B     |
|           |      |            |
| buttonA   |      | property   |
+-----------+      +------------+
```

Code:

```
  @IBAction func buttonA(_ sender: Any) {

    let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let windowBWC = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "Window B Controller") as! WindowBWindowController

    let viewBVC = windowBWC.contentViewController as! ViewBViewController

    // set viewBVC property


    let application = NSApplication.shared
    guard let window = viewBVC.view.window else { return }
    application.runModal(for: window)

    window.close()
  }
```

And in the files:

```
// WindowBWindowController.swift

class WindowBWindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.

      print("windowDidLoad")
    }
}
```

```
// ViewBViewController.swift
class ViewBViewController: NSViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    print("viewDidLoad")
  }
}
```

When I click the button, the view will show, but I had the viewDidLoad first and then is the windowDidLoad, this is counter intuitive for me, there should be a window first, later then is the view.

Comment: Loading the view is part of loading the window. `windowDidLoad` is called when the window nib file, including the views, is loaded.

Comment: @Willeke thanks, I guess I read somewhere the window will load on need, maybe this explains why the window loaded later than view.

Comment: if you call [super viewDidLoad] you should be safe to ask for view's window. Also apple engineers like to call "viewDidMoveToWindow" to see if you have a valid window.